# SQL developer- the network adapter could not establish the connection

Tags: sql, oracle, networking, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to oracle database and i was trying to set up SQL developer.After installation when I open it and make a new connection it gives me "IO error: the network adapter could not establish the connection".I tried to look up for the solution everywhere but nothing worked.Can someone please explain me in detail hoe to fix this thing?[image]

Comment: It means server is not reachable at the given address. Is Oracle XE installed on your system?

Comment: I don't think so.Is there any way I can check whether it's there on my system.I use ubuntu 16.04 lts

Comment: if you didn't' install XE, it's not there

Answer (score -1):

You have installed SQL Developer, the client.

It's effectively limited to working with files and offline data models.

If you want to do database work, you need a database.

Here's your [options for getting started](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/12/i-have-oracle-sql-developer-installed-now-what/).

Answer (score -2):

You have to start the listener with

```
lsnrctl start
```